# Pattern attribute for Email validation is not working in html5

Tags: html, model-view-controller

Using Html5 I've a view which contains an email input field.

So to validate the correct email address I am using pattern attribute for validation.

But that is not working correctly, the problem I am facing here is though I enter invalid email address as `abc@gmail` the validation is not working.
i tested the same regex pattern in fiddler, it is working fine there, but coming to my application it is not working correctly. Please help me out with this.
Here is my view:

```html
<form>

  <input type="email" 
    class="form-control" 
    data-val="true" 
    data-val-required="please enter an email address"
    pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,4}$" 
    required>
  
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet - Escape the dot: `[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$` https://regex101.com/r/CrvvVi/1 - also 2,4 is not a good choice. In general your regex is too restrictive

Comment: TLDs aren't limited to 4 characters any more, there are lots of characters that can appear in the username portion of an address that you forgot about, and capital letters ARE allowed. That regex is *awful* and will generate many false positives.

Answer (score 1):

Regex should be

**[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,}$**

instead of 

**[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,4}$**

So the html input would be:

```
<input type="email"
   class="form-control"
   data-val="true"
   data-val-required="please enter an email address"
   pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$"
   required>
```

NOTE: difference in regex is `{2,}` and `{2,4}`

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, your regex is working in fiddler but in my code it is not working correctly

Comment: can you make a small fiddle or pen to test it out?